# Error of ModelStructure/Outputs by using FMU container

Tags: simulation, modelica, fmi

I am trying to combine three FMUs into one FMU that contains all of the three. Specifically, I have one FMU of a pandapower electricity network and 2 FMUs that are CSV files converted to FMUs by using [PythonFMU tool](https://github.com/NTNU-IHB/PythonFMU/blob/master/pythonfmu/tests/test_csvslave.py). All of the FMUs have been tested by the [FMU Check](https://fmu-check.herokuapp.com/) and they have been simulated together to check that everything works fine.

Then I am using [FMPy tool](https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy/blob/master/tests/test_fmu_container.py) to combine all of them together and export successfully the final FMU.

However, when I am trying to validate this I get the following error:

```
ModelStructure/Outputs must have exactly one entry for each variable with causality="output".
```

Any idea of what is wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying to validate  with the FMU Check?
You do not seem to use pyfmi, but fmpy. So please adpat the tag to fmpy

Comment: @ChristianBertsch I am getting this error either by trying to validate the FMU through FMU Check or by trying to simulate the FMU with FMPy.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be fixed in https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy/issues/281#issuecomment-879092943
You should try to re-generate the containerized FMU with the developmenet branch of fmpy.